Determining when a triangle can be inscribed in a rectangle

Given the side lengths of a triangle and a rectangle, how to check if the triangle can be inscribed in the rectangle?

I had found a solution but couldn't prove it formally. Also, I wonder if there is any other approach as the only person who solved it (when I posted this problem in Sololearn - a coding community,) had the same idea.
Try it out yourself!
My Approach:

 Pin one of the two vertices of the longest side of the triangle to a vertex of the rectangle and rotate the triangle and check if it (or any of its three mirror orientations) can be inscribed in the rectangle. This gives a few mathematical inequalities involving distances and are easy to evaluate.

Basis of the Approach:

 It works because any triangle that lies inside the rectangle, can be translated inside the rectangle so that one (or both) of the longest side vertices touches rectangle's vertex.

Visual explanation:
In the diagram $A$, $B$ and $C$ are the sides of triangle and $A$ is the longest. $X$ and $Y$ are the sides of rectangle and $X$ is longer than $Y$. If $C$'s length lies between the smallest and longest distance between the dotted lines $bb'$ and $cc'$ or similiar condition is satisfied but with sides $C$ and $B$ swapped (mirror orientation) then only the triangle can be inscribed.

Perhaps I misunderstood the answer. If you pin one end of the longest side of the triangle to a vertex of the rectangle and find that neither reflection of the triangle can be rotated inside the rectangle, what is your conclusion? Do you conclude that the triangle does not fit in the rectangle, or do you try the other end of the longest side?

I'm sorry I should have stated more clearly. There will be three other mirror orientations not just one. One for each of longest side vertex pinned at that point. So yeah, if none of those orientations fit in, the triangle can't be inscribed.

Add the maths equations involved and show visualization

@AderinsolaJoshua I have added a diagram. Equations are many and quite messy so I have not written them. I would rather like to share my Python code of it: https://sololearn.com/compiler-playground/ccWGrWYUH07P

Now I'm almost sure this method is provably correct. I think there is even a question about triangles that was answered by a proof that would work for this too.
